# Sending a Preflight to server when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, cors

I am having a problem in my site that it is sending a preflight to the server when it shouldn't
this is the function that are making the problem

```
    function getInfo(type,end,message,header){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        if (this.status == 200) {
                            let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                            resolve({ response });
                        } else {
                            reject(new Error(`Falha a obter dados`));
                        }
                    }
                };
            xhttp.open(type, "https://magno.di.uevora.pt/tweb/t1/"+end, true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", header);
            xhttp.send(message);
            });
    }
    function addagendamento(){
        let message=JSON.stringify({
            user_id:3,
            vaccine:"gripe",
            entity_id:3
        });
        getInfo("POST","schedule/add",message,"application/json")
        .then(({ response }) => {    
        
            })
            .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error:", error.message);
        });
    }
```

the code of the server side is done by the professor and i have a friend with similar code that ins't get this error on his pc on his code, but in my code the error still appends on his pc, altough i tried is code on my pc and get the same error.
this is the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://magno.di.uevora.pt/tweb/t1/schedule/add' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
trabalho.js:339 Error: Falha a obter dados
(anônimo) @ trabalho.js:339
Promise.catch (assíncrono)
addagendamento @ trabalho.js:338
onclick @ test.html?idU=3:76
trabalho.js:325 
POST https://magno.di.uevora.pt/tweb/t1/schedule/add net::ERR_FAILED
```

From what i research it has to do with sending a prefligth to the server and it doesn't handle it well but it shouldn't even send the prefligth.(I think)

Comment: The premise of your question is incorrect: [per the Fetch standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests), a cross-origin request that includes a `Content-Type` header whose value is `application/json` triggers CORS preflight.